# album-photo laravel gallery. error on updating photos in an album

Tags: php, laravel

i have been trying to update photos in an album but i cant get it right. i know that i need to get the album id of the photos that i want to update but i cannot get the right logic for the request.

this is the error am getting whenever i request for an update

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'album_id' cannot be null (SQL: update `photos` set `album_id` = , `photo` = IMG-20190527-WA0001_1570703623.jpg, `size` = 275807, `updated_at` = 2019-10-10 10:33:44 where `id` = 197)
```

the photos model for the application is as shown below

```
class Photos extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('album_id', 'description', 'photo', 'title', 'size');

    public function album(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
}
}
```

this is what i have tried for the update logic in the photosController. i have tried to request for the album id but it does not seem to work

```
public function edit($id){
    $photo = Photos::find($id);
    return view('photos/edit')->with('photo', $photo);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'photo' => 'required | max:15000'
    ]);


    $path = [];


            //get filename with extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();

            //get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //get extension
            $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //create new file name
            $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            //get file size
            $filesize = $request->file('photo')->getClientSize();

            $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('public/photos'.$request->input('album_id'), $filenameToStore);   

            $photo = Photos::find($id);
            $photo->album_id = $request->input('album_id');
            $photo->size = $filesize;
            $photo->photo = $filenameToStore;
            $photo->save();

    return $path;
}
```

each time i return the path for the photo am updating there is no id for the photo. only happens when i omit the save method

```
public/photos//IMG-20190527-WA0001_1570706571.jpg
```

photo edit php view code

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['PhotosController@update', $photo->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])!!}
        {{Form::file('photo')}}
        {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}  
        {{Form::submit('submit')}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

database model for photos table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('album_id');
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('photos');
}
```

help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at this line

```php
$photo->album_id = $request->input('album_id');
```

You don't have an input in your form with the name `album_id`

You can either create a hidden one and assign it the value

```html
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['PhotosController@update', $photo->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])!!}
{{Form::file('photo')}}
{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
{{-- Here --}}
{{Form::hidden('album_id', $photo->album->id)}}
{{Form::submit('submit')}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

or get it from the relationship like so

```php
$photo->album_id = $photo->album->id;
```

> Note that you're also using that null|empty value here

```php
$path = $request->file('photo')
 ->storeAs('public/photos'.$request->input('album_id'), $filenameToStore);
```

So make sure to update that too

Hope this helps