# More info about this question album-photo laravel gallery. error on updating photos in an album

Tags: php, laravel

Danny Gitonga asked re:
[album-photo laravel gallery. error on updating photos in an album](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321878/album-photo-laravel-gallery-error-on-updating-photos-in-an-album)

I am trying to accomplish the same thing and have the same problem.

Saly 3301 answered, as I am a beginner with Laravel I don't quite understand the answer, could someone elaborate please, perhaps give more details.

This is the youtube video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXYCnYRalaw
If you fastforward to the 1hour 15 minute part that is where my problem occurs.

I hope it ok to link, saves a lot duplicating.
Your help is appreciated