# Displaying images in aLaravel photo gallery

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a photo gallery. In my previous question here:

[More info about this question album-photo laravel gallery. error on updating photos in an album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583955/more-info-about-this-question-album-photo-laravel-gallery-error-on-updating-pho?r=SearchResults&s=2|82.1918)

I related to another user because I was having the same problem, I have done some further investigation I have found the issue is with this line in the show.blade.php file

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="/storage/photos/{{$photo-> album_id}}/{{$photo->photo}}"
alt="{{$photo->title}}">
```

The problem is with {{$photo-> album_id}} . If I substitute that with {{$album->id}}
it show the image, however it only shows the current image no others

In the browser, viewing the source it shows this

```
/storage/photos//theimage.jpg
```

Here are the relevant files

`````
````<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Photo;

class PhotoController extends Controller
{
    //album_id is hidden field
    public function create($album_id){
      return view('photos.create')->with('album_id', $album_id);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
          'title' => 'required',
          'photo' => 'image|max:1999'
        ]);



        $filetostore =$request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();

        $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('public/photos/'.$request->input('album_id'), $filetostore);

              //upload photo
                $photo = new Photo;
                $photo->album_id = $request->input('album_id');
                $photo->title = $request->input('title');
                $photo->photo = $filetostore;

                $photo->save();

                return redirect('/albums/'.$request->input('album_id'))->with('success','Photo Uploaded');
      }

      public function show($id){
        $photo = Photo::find($id);
        return view('photos.show')->with('photo', $photo);
      }

}````

````@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h3> Upload Photo </h3>
  {!!Form::open(['action'=> 'PhotoController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype'=> 'multipart/form-data'])!!}
  {{Form::text('title','')}}
  {{Form::hidden('album_id', $album_id)}}
  {{Form::file('photo')}}
  {{Form::submit('submit')}}
  {!!Form::close()!!}

@endsection````

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

````class Photo extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = array('album_id','photo', 'title');

      public function album(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');

      }
}````
`````

I don't get why album_id has no value. I have checked the files many times but I can't find any problems:

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should `dd($photo)` or `logger($photo)` to see the real/final values of the $photo attributes.

And also check your database table columns to make sure if everything is ok, especially the `ablum_id` column.

Comment: This Could be a comment instead of an answer